# How to retrieve data in php sent over AJAX post call?

Tags: php, ajax

Basically I am trying to send the data using ajax post call to php. I am getting response success and I can see the data in my console which I have sent as well on Network Form Data in Headers. But on PHP page I am not getting the data.

```
var OrderNumber = "60019";
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

 $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: "page.php",
        data: {OrderNumber,cars},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },

    });
});
```

php file to fetch the data

```
<?php
 $OrderNumber="";
 $cars="";
if (isset($_REQUEST["OrderNumber"]) && $_REQUEST["OrderNumber"] != "") {
    $OrderNumber = strtoupper(trim($_REQUEST["OrderNumber"]));
} else if (isset($_POST["OrderNumber"]) && $_POST["OrderNumber"] != "") {
    $OrderNumber = strtoupper(trim($_POST["OrderNumber"]));
}

if (isset($_REQUEST["cars"]) && $_REQUEST["cars"] != "") {
     $cars = $_REQUEST["cars"];
 } else if (isset($_POST["cars"]) && $_POST["cars"] != "") {
     $cars = $_POST["cars"];
 }

echo($OrderNumber);
var_dump(cars);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

On PHP side I am getting everything null. It would be really help me understand and learn this ajax to php call concept. I tried to follow lot of tutorials on the internet but it still I am missing something. Though I am trying to figure out and will keep posted. Any suggestions or advice where I am going wrong?

Comment: use a `colon` between parameter and value in the `data` argument - or `data: {'OrderNumber':OrderNumber,'cars':cars},` ~ I'd suggest using `$_POST` rather than `$_REQUEST`

Comment: I added colon between parameter and value and used $_POST as you suggested but still I am not able display data on php side but no errors or warnings. i can see in console data being sent over successfully

Comment: The [.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation would be a good place to start.  There are examples towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: Divide and conquer. First make sure that your API is working. Use PostMan or curl to send requests to it and make sure that you are getting the expected responses.

Comment: "*But on PHP page I am not getting the data.*" What is this supposed to mean? If your AJAX call is successful and returns the data, then you are getting the data to PHP.

Comment: As we pass on data via forms to another webpage forms actually can redirect the page with the data if I am not mistaken that's what I was trying to to do using ajax

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `jQuery` would treat passing an array into the `data` parameter whether it would encode as JSON or attempt to send "as-is" so if `{'OrderNumber':OrderNumber,'cars':cars}` does not work because `cars` is an array you might need to encode `cars` like so:

```
{'OrderNumber':OrderNumber,'cars':JSON.stringify( cars )}
```

With the PHP you might consider:

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        $errors=array();
        $args=array(
            'OrderNumber'   =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'cars'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
        );

        foreach( array_keys( $args ) as $field ){
            if( !isset( $_POST[ $field ] ) ) $errors[]=sprintf( 'The field "%s" is not set', $field );
        }

        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
            if( !in_array( $field, array_keys( $args ) ) )$errors[]=sprintf( 'Unknown field "%s"', $field );
        }

        if( empty( $errors ) ){
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );
            /* there will now be a cars and a OrderNumber variable to play with */

            $OrderNumber=strtoupper( $OrderNumber  );

        } else {
            exit( json_encode( $errors ) );
        }
    }

?>
```

Any unspecified fields in the POST array will be dropped and any missing fields will cause an error - the resultant POST array is cast into variables using `extract` ( which because of the above should be ok )

Comment: Yes it worked. But what If I want to display OrderNumber and cars array into same php webpage where I am retrieving data from ajax page.php like just echoing out.

Comment: @J.Doe - please explain what you mean `"display OrderNumber and cars array into same php webpage where I am retrieving data from"`, @gre_gor ? was that comment for my benefit or the OP? ( presumably for mine )

Comment: As we pass on data via forms to another webpage forms actually can redirect the page with the data if I am not mistaken that's what I was trying to to do using ajax. yes your comment helped me a lot thanks

Comment: OK - you could get the ajax function to return the content from that "other page" and display on the same page but if you redirect to the "other page" there is no need for ajax